# Wiki-tag edit error is non-descriptive

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, tag-wiki, error-message

I've been editing some wiki entries on the new Expatriates site, and started to get the following error:

[image]

When I go to a normal post, I see what is presumably the proper explanation:

[image]

Can the Wiki Tag edit error be updated to show a more meaningful error message?

Comment: Related: [Submitting an edit after you hit the suggested edit limit should not return a server error](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281952/242209).  Also this might be better tagged as a [tag:feature-request] if it is not in fact a bug.

Answer (score 2):

The situation has improved; first of all, the 'Edit tag info' button is no longer shown if the queue is full:

[image]

It's still possible to start the edit, with the 'Improve tag info' link on the 'questions' page of the tag (perhaps that link can be removed):

[image]

If you try to submit the edit anyway, you get a proper error message:

[image]

Comment: "the 'Edit tag info' button is no longer shown if the queue is full" I've seen like 2-3 MSO reports wondering where it went though.

Comment: Perhaps it should be visible but disabled (with a tooltip indicating the reason)?