# Is there a bug in the suggested edits queue?

Tags: support, status-completed, review, suggested-edits, beta-sites

Over on [Expatriates.SE](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/), us low-rep users can no longer submit edit suggestions (as mentioned in an [earlier meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226652/165502)), and we're told the review queue is full:

[image]

However, at least one high-rep user shows that there is nothing in the review queue:

[image]

Is this a bug, or is there some logical reason for this discrepancy?

See also the relevant [Meta.Expatriates.SE question](https://expatriates.meta.stackexchange.com/q/158/28).

---

### Update:

Our hi-rep user reports that if he goes to my profile, as an example, and clicks on suggested edits, he can see some tag-wiki suggestions, but cannot review them:

[image]

Comment: Well, technically that one user could have skipped all 200 edits, or someone else could have opened up all 200 edits in different tabs to pull out a lock on all of them (not sure if that would work, actually).  Those both seem rather unlikely though.

Comment: @Servy it is my screenshoot and I didn't skip any edits.

Comment: new mods were appointed which should be  able to tak e care of the queue: http://meta.expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/162/please-give-a-warm-welcome-to-your-new-moderation-team

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on your edit, it appears that you have 200 tag wiki edits that are all filling up the queue.  In the short term, you might want to get a mod to just zip through the queue if possible and create at least *some* space.  You may also need to temporarily decrease the rep requirement for [the permission to review tag wiki edits](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits), so that other higher reputation users can work on the queue.  Currently you have exactly one user with enough rep to approve such edits, and he only got enough 4 hours ago.  (And of course, you need 2-3 reviewers per post, so he's still not enough.)

Comment: Ha! That's kind of funny. Is it actually possible to reduce that requirement?

Comment: @Flimzy Yes.  Notice how the permissions for quite a lot of things are already lower than on graduated sites.  The permissions are all configurable per site.  On graduated sites you generally need 2k reputation to edit posts/review suggested edits.  (Not tag wiki edits.)  And none of your users are even to that point.

Comment: @Flimzy they are working on getting moderators in place. Once that happens they should be able to handle the review queue.

Comment: Who can edit those requirements? I apparently cannot on the site where I am a moderator.  On beta sites, all the requirements are halved (and on private beta, halved again), if memory serves.

Comment: @Flimzy Probably CMs, at least that's what I would expect.  If nothing else, they'd know who to talk to.  While the numbers you're referring to are conventions, there are examples that diverge from those.  For example, creating tags on SO takes like 3x more rep than any other graduated site, and comments on meta take 1 rep.

Comment: @Flimzy Each site has a per-site set of reputation values for its privileges which can be changed by the SE team to suit the site more specifically. The "beta" and "graduated" privilege sets are just default templates.

Comment: @animuson: Interesting to know.  Thanks.

Comment: @animuson: In that case, is it reasonable to temporarily lower the wiki-tag review threshold for Expatriates.SE?

Comment: Well, the site [got no moderators whatsoever](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), not even a single mod so no wonder such things happen.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Apparently Expats is one of the fastest ever sites to make it through private beta, and I'm told that the success is running a little ahead of the normal process for appointing people...

Comment: @ShadowWizard and the SE team has responded by putting mods in place.

Comment: @DanielE.Shub yep, "74 reviews today" - three more days and the queue will be empty again.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's not *that* important that it be empty, just that it not be full.

Comment: @ShadowWizard it looks empty to me. Why do you think it is not empty yet?

Comment: @DanielE.Shub weird, it got 200 items, only 20 hours ago, and says 74 reviews made today. So the numbers don't add up.

Comment: @ShadowWizard where do you see those numbers?

Comment: @DanielE aka StrongBad [here](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/stats). :)