# Decap the suggested edits queue

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits

The suggested edits queue has a maximum size of 200, [as a new site recently ran afoul of](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226744/223030). This is for some reason that I don't know, and probably seemed legit at the time. Then `/review` happened, and nearly any queue could contain thousands of posts (case in point: SO's infamous close vote queue). Except that after years of review-y goodness, pending suggested edits are still limited to 200.

If 200 suggested edits accumulate, nobody else can suggest edits until they start getting cleared. With `/review` technology able to technically support queue sizes of over a hundred thousand, **why do we still have this problem?**

Comment: A beta site with [219 questions](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions) *in total* has 200 unresolved `/review` flags?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Tag wiki edits, apparently.

Comment: What happened to the mods?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Apparently Expatriates doesn't yet have any. (That's what the linked question says.)

Comment: How can you have a public beta site without any appointed pro-tem mods? *[sigh]*  Well, Tim Post and Anna Lear have accounts there.

Comment: FWIW, `/review` existed for a *long* time before suggested edits ever existed, and the queues usually had way more than 200 items in them. Review was just *revamped* to the system that is in place now.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Mods are typically chosen after a couple of weeks of public beta (to give a bit of time for potential candidates to become interested and observe how they've behaved so far). 200 suggested edits is highly unusual (20 would be unusually high), there's something weird going on there (someone copy-pasting Wikipedia for every tag would be my bet, unless it's a spam attack) and upping the limit wouldn't solve the problem — rather there should be a limit of pending suggestions per user.