# Submitting an edit after you hit the suggested edit limit should not return a server error

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, rate-limiting

I ran into a bug on [Retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/214/621) where I hit the suggested edit limit while editing tag wikis without realizing it, and attempting to submit any subsequent suggestions returned a server error, rather than alerting me I hit [the limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281202).

Can the red tooltip that says "An error occurred submitting this post." be changed to something like "You have hit the suggested edit limit of 20 posts, please wait for your current suggestions to be reviewed before submitting additional suggestions." or something like that?

Some additional information about this scenario based on [Shog's comments](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214/cant-submit-tag-wiki-edits/215?noredirect=1#comment345_215):

I had several suggested edits queued up in multiple tabs.  I was prepared to submit them one by one, as the 30 second limit lifted.  The fact that I was trying to submit several forms that had been open for 30+ minutes was probably the culprit.  Thanks Shog for looking into this.

Comment: To clarify:  The 20 posts was the number of outstanding Suggested Edits that were awaiting review.

Comment: @Chenmunka right, I think they were all mine based on [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281202/242209) on rate limiting

Comment: You got the error when trying to submit edit to ordinary post, or to a tag wiki?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I could only test suggesting a tag wiki since I already had the edit privilege on ordinary posts.  I'm not sure if the error would arise in that scenario as well.

Comment: In that case, it's a dupe.

Comment: Reopen voter(s): the problem is the generic error message, not the actual reason why you can't submit the edit. This is a duplicate.