# "An error occurred submitting the post" while editing a new tag

Tags: support, bug, error-message

I created the tag `proxybroker` on Stack Overflow and then tried to add the excerpt and description, but I got:

> An error occurred submitting the post

while trying to `Save Edits`.

I also tried removing the description, but it isn't working either.

Comment: Did you try to submit it again after the initial error (that is, how many times did you try it?)?

Comment: Related? [Submitting an edit after you hit the suggested edit limit should not return a server error](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281952/242209)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the suggested edit queue was full at the time and we do a real bad job of showing a coherent error message in that case.

I'll make myself a note to look into this more when I have time, but for now, the queue numbers look good at the moment, so if you try again, it should go through.

Comment: Related: I just got [the similar message *"An error occurred submitting the edit."*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pthMa.png) at *[Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour)* (suggested edit). Only in the third try did it succeed.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Funnily enough, a different issue. :) There's a null reference happening when Elasticsearch is in trouble, which is what happened a bit ago. I'll see about fixing that up.

Comment: @AdamLear, On SO I am getting the same error, Can you help me to resolve my suggested edits to clear queue ?