# What is the maximum number of edits that can enter the Suggested Edit Review Queue?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rate-limiting

This question ([Wiki-tag edit error is non-descriptive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226652/242209)) seems to suggest that there is a maximum number of suggested edits that can be in the queue at a time.  What is this value?  Is it different for each site on Stack Exchange?

Comment: Well, it [***was***](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/84398/152859) 30...

Comment: @ShadowWizard Is this a dupe then?  I don't know how valid that post is.  Happy to close as a dupe if the information is updated to be accurate.

Comment: There is a comment saying 200, looking for official stamp so I can edit that answer and yes, this is still a dupe. (Will close if/when I find official answer)

Comment: @ShadowWizard how do you know that information is still valid?

Comment: http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5152797#5152797 :)